# Pandas group by id if condition is met and drop rows that are not meeting condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where there is multiple **user_id** rows with different **status**, if there is at least one row for **user_id** where **status = 'VALID'**, I then want to remove the rows with **status = 'DELETED'** for the **user_id**. Original dataframe looks like this:

| user_id | alert_source | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | research | deleted |
| 1 | research | deleted |
| 1 | research | valid |
| 2 | research | deleted |
| 2 | research | valid |

I want my clean dataframe look like this

| user_id | alert_source | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | research | valid |
| 2 | research | valid |

Same goes if all the **status** values would be equal to **'deleted'**. I want to remove the duplicates and have just one row of that **user_id** to be the desired **status** – in this case **'deleted'**.

I tried googling, but for this scenario I didn't find any relatable sources that could've helped me.

Comment: What should happen if there are two rows for the same user ID and status, but with different alert_source?

Comment: I have more dataframes that I'm dealing with, I take data from database so I filter out only those that have desired alert_source, then do the same for another alert_source (since I have only two alert_sources) and merge the dataframes on user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `drop_duplicates` method twice:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "user_id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
        "alert_source": ['research', 'research', 'research', 'research', 'research', 'research'],
        "status": ['deleted', 'deleted', 'valid', 'deleted', 'valid', 'deleted']
    }
)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["user_id", "status"])
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset="user_id", keep='last')
```

Which will result in:

```
   user_id alert_source   status
2        1     research    valid
4        2     research    valid
5        3     research  deleted
```

But with this approach (i.e. with using `keep='last'` keyword argument) you have to make sure that `status` column is sorted alphabetically.